# Understanding of definition of continuity (and uniform continuity)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

**Definition1** Let $E$ be nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

i) $f$ said to be *continuous* at a point $a\in E$ if and only if given $\varepsilon >0$ there is a $\delta >0$ such that

$\left| x-a\right| < \delta$ and $x\in E$ imply $\left| f\left( x\right) -f\left( a\right) \right| < \varepsilon$.

ii) $f$ is said to be *continuous* on $E$ if and only if $f$ is continuous at every $x\in E$.

**My question is**: 'ii)' is actually uniformly continuous, isn't it?

**Definition2.** Let $E$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f: E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is said to be *uniformly continuous* on $E$ if and only if for every $\varepsilon >0$ there is a $\delta >0$ such that

$\left| x-0\right| < \delta$ and $x,a\in E$ imply $\left| f\left( x\right) -f\left( a\right) \right| < \varepsilon$

Comment: I think the "ii" is the definition of a continuous function. There's a difference between continuity at a point, continuity and uniform continuity at a point

Comment: No, ii) is continuity. The choice of $\delta$ for a given $\varepsilon$ can depend on $a$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I added definition of uniform continuity. Now, what is the difference between definition1 and definition2? Can you explain clearly?

Comment: In symbols, the difference is $(\forall a \in E)(\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\dotsc)$ versus $(\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall a \in E)(\dotsc)$. In uniform continuity, the same $\delta$ must work for all $a$, in plain continuity, the $\delta$ can depend on $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuous at $a$: Let $f: S\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function. The function is continuous at $a$ if $$a\in S,\,\, \forall \epsilon >0\,\,\exists \delta >0 : \forall x\in S\,\, |x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon $$
notice that $a\in S$ is given at the beginning!

Uniform continuity: $$\,\, \forall \epsilon >0\,\,\exists \delta >0 : \forall a,x\in S\,\, |x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon $$

So the difference is that the value of $\delta$ in continuity depends on both $\epsilon$ and on the point $a$, whereas for uniform continuity the value of $\delta$ depends only on $\epsilon$ and not on the point at which the definition is being checked!

For example $f(x) = x^2$ is clearly continuous (at every point in the domain) but not uniformly continuous! (try to prove it by contradiction!).

[To give you an intuition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXkQqCBLRp8)

Answer (score 0):

In the first definition it is evident that the value of $\delta$ depends on the chosen $\epsilon$ but also , in general, from the value of $a$: i.e. from the point in which we test the continuity.This is the definition of continuity  at a point.

The second definition does not Explicitly cite the point $ a $, and this can lead to the impression that the definition is independent from the point . But the definition explicitly refers to the  previous definition of continuity at a point, so, also in this case the value of $\delta$ is , in general, dependent from the points in the interval, in contrast to the definition of [uniform continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity), that requires that $\delta$ is independent from the point.

The definition of uniform continuity added to the question is non correct.

The last row must be:

$ \forall x,a \in E$ such that $\left| x-a\right| < \delta$  we have $\left| f\left( x\right) -f\left( a\right) \right| < \varepsilon$